# Geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync throw "Class not registered" exception c#

Tags: windows-runtime

I run next code in blank project and got "Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))"

```
private Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geolocator locator = new Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geolocator();

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var position = await this.locator.GetGeopositionAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
        }
    }
```

Also, I tried to run [Geolocation Sample 8.1](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Geolocation-2483de66) (c# and JS) but got the same exception and I tried to run this sample not on 1 PC and not on 1 network. All the same.
I have win8.1 rtm and VS2013 RC on my laptop.

Also,  I run this code and Microsoft sample on ARM tablet with 8.1 Pro preview (with GNSS module) and on tablet(i5-3317U Processor and without GPS module) with 8.1 rtm. I didn't get this exception and all works fine. So I think it only occured on PC/Simulator.
How to test GeoLocation app on PC/Simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this code on 8.0 - work fine.
On 8.1 rtm still got class not registered exception.
I think I need to add some library, but don't know where.

UPD:
I found where is problem.
I have **Pro N** version of win 8.1. In **Pro N** this code throw exception.
On **Enterprise** and **Pro** versions all work fine.

Comment: Strange, it doesn't make sense, "N and KN editions
The features in the N and KN Editions are the same as their equivalent full versions, but do not include Windows Media Player or other Windows Media-related technologies, such as Windows Media Center and Windows DVD Maker".

Comment: I know, but it's fact :) I have 4 pc and 2 laptops with win 8.1 **PRO N** installed from 1 disk. All of them got exceptions in this code. If anyone have Pro N  - maybe then can run this code and check it.

Comment: in msdn forum one guy say that he reproduce that bug in Enterprise **N** version.

Answer (score 1):

The code works, I tested this on my computer:

```
        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var locator = new Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geolocator();
        var position = await locator.GetGeopositionAsync();
    }
```

I tested both on Windows 8 with Visual Studio 2012 a**s well as Windows 8.1 (Preview) and Visual Studio 2013 (preview)**. As long as the capabilities were set there were no problems. I did not download the sample, the code is fairly straight forward to write even for complex scenarios. Look at the sample for inspiration, but code your own. Always easier not having to debug somebody elses logic :)

Code was tested 'on pc' as well as simulator (although there shouldn't be a difference since the simulator IS your PC as it remote desktop's to your own computer)

Make sure that you set capabilities for location:

[image]

Use the location option in the simulator to set a specific address if you want:

[image]

My breakpoint

[image]

If all fails, do the usual. Uninstall the app, clean and rebuild, restart computer and Visual Studio, and check that the location capability is set by using getting the charm bar once the app is installed and running, and select permissions. It should say that it has permissions, see below:

[image]

Best of luck!

Comment: Hello Iris! Yes, I tried all what you write before, but it's dosn't work not only on my PC. Summary I tested this code on 3 PC and 1 laptop.

Answer (score 0):

As said "zedkommander" above, error com from "N" version of windows 8.

But he didn't give the solution, so i'm going to give it :

Microsoft employee confirmed this problem :

> This behaviour is indeed specific to the “N” editions.  For geolocation to work on N-editions of Windows, the Microsoft Media Feature Pack needs to be installed.
>
> Geolocation has a dependency on WPD (Windows Portable Devices) infrastructure which is not present in N editions until the feature pack is installed.

If you want to fix it, you need to install "Microsoft Media Feature Pack" by clicking here : https://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/download/details.aspx?id=30685